# JQuery function to fire on slideout Div appearing the first time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a slideout div that slides when the user places the mouse over.
That all work perfectly but now I would like to also fire a JQuery call the first time the div appears.

I'm using this code here

```
http://usabilitypost.com/2011/04/19/pure-css-slideout-interface/
```

So conceptually,
is there a way to trap when the div slides out for the 1st time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ywksau4/2/):

```
var counter = 0;
$('#slideout').hover(function(){
    if(counter > 0) {
        $(this).css('background','blue');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background','red');
        counter++;
    }
});
```

This does a simple counter and only runs the red background once. The rest of the time is blue. This should be good enough for you to target the first time it shows.